# Token StartElement in state EndRootElement would result in an invalid XML document

Tags: c#, xml, powerpoint

I am working on a project where as I create a power point document from c#.
It's all going very well but for some reason on one of my methods I am getting this error:

"Token StartElement in state EndRootElement would result in an invalid XML document."

Here is my method:

```
 private static void slideLayout6XML()
    {
        FileStream slideLayout6Stream = new FileStream( slideLayout6, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write );
        XmlWriter slideLayout6Writer = null;

        try
        {
            XmlWriterSettings contentTypesSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            contentTypesSettings.Indent = true;
            slideLayout6Writer = XmlWriter.Create( slideLayout6Stream, contentTypesSettings );

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartDocument( true );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "sldLayout" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "preserve", "1" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "type", "titleOnly" );

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main" );

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "cSld" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "name", "Title Only" );

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "spTree" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "nvGrpSpPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "cNvpr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "name", "" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "id", "1" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "cNvGrpSpPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "nvPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "grpSpPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "xfrm" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "off" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "y", "0" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "x", "0" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "ext" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "y", "0" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "x", "0" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "chOff" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "y", "0" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "x", "0" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "chExt" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "y", "0" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "x", "0" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "sp" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "nvSpPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "cNvPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "name", "Title 1" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "id", "2" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "cNvSpPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "spLocks" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "noGrp", "1" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "nvPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "ph" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "type", "title" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "txBody" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "bodyPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "lstStyle" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "p" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "r" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "rPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "lang", "en-US" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "smtClean", "0" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "t" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteRaw( "Click to edit Master title style" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "endParaRPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "lang", "en-US" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "sp" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "nvSpPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "cNvPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "name", "Date Placeholder 2" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "id", "3" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "cNvSpPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "spLocks" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "noGrp", "1" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "nvPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "ph" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "type", "dt" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "idx", "10" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "sz", "half" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "txBody" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "bodyPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "lstStyle" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "p" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "fld" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "type", "datetime1" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "id", "{32E0D616-E0F4-45FD-A59D-58900C81D413}" );

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "rPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "lang", "en-US" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "smtClean", "0" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "t" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteRaw( "5/17/2012" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "endParaRpR" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "lang", "en-US" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "sp" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "nvSpPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "cNvPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "name", "Footer Placeholder 3" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "id", "4" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "cNvSpPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "spLocks" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "noGrp", "1" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "nvPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "ph" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "type", "ftr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "idx", "11" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "sz", "quarter" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "txBody" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "bodyPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "lstStyle" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "p" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "r" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "rPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "lang", "en-US" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "smtClean", "0" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "t" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteRaw( "Crowded Igloo Business System" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "endParaRPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "lang", "en-US" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "sp" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "nvSpPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "cNvPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "name", "Slide Number Placeholder 4" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "id", "5" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "cNvSpPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "spLocks" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "noGrp", "1" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "nvPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "ph" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "type", "sldNum" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "idx", "12" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "sz", "quarter" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "txBody" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "bodyPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "lstStyle" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "p" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "fld" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "type", "slidenum" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "id", "{8B131516-2DB0-4AAA-89BA-2724DE07B6A2}" );
            
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "rPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "lang", "en-US" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "smtClean", "0" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "t" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteRaw( "<#>" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "endParaRPr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "lang", "en-US" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "extLst" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "ext" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "uri", "{BB962C8B-B14F-4D97-AF65-F5344CB8AC3E}" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p14", "creationId", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteAttributeString( "val", "3805825225" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();

            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "p", "clrMapOvr" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteStartElement( "a", "masterClrMapping" );
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndElement();
            
            slideLayout6Writer.WriteEndDocument();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (slideLayout6Writer != null)
                slideLayout6Writer.Flush();

            slideLayout6Writer.Close();
        }
    }
```

Sorry for the massive method but in this method it throws the error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My guess would be that you have closed the outermost element, so you are not allowed to open a new one because XML only allows one element at the outermost level.

This kind of interface is very handy for writing XML and I use it myself, but it can be a pig to debug if you make any nesting mistakes. I've been known to use my own wrapper for the interface in which the calls to endElement have to specify the matching tag name; the wrapper can then check the correct nesting of the calls, which helps greatly to identify where the error is.

Comment: Thanks you were right. i closed a element that needed a start element. elements without attribute strings can get quite confusing.

Comment: Helped in my case, was accidentally closing main parent node as soon as it was created, preventing attempts to write child nodes.

Answer (score 1):

you call startelement 81 times.. guess what: you NOT call endelement 81 times...

so make sure start and end match correctly ;)