# Add multiple elements to XML C# using textwriter

Tags: c#, xml, xmlwriter

I need the following output

```
<BatchFile>
   <BatchFileHeader>
     <MessageType>MSG103</MessageType>
     <Version>456</Version>
   <BatchFileHeader>

   <Vendor>
     <VendorType>VVV</VendorType>
   </Vendor>
</BatchFile>
```

Following is my code

```
StringWriter stringwriter = new StringWriter();
XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringwriter);
xmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
xmlTextWriter.WriteStartDocument();

xmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement("BatchFileHeader");
xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("MessageType", "MSG103"); 
xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("MessageVersion", "456"); 
xmlTextWriter.WriteEndElement();

xmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement("Vendor");
xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("Vendor", "VVV"); 
xmlTextWriter.WriteEndElement();
```

But I get the following error

> token startelement in state epilog would result in an invalid xml
>   document

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you writing the `<BatchFile>` element, Because XML only allows one element at the outermost level.See this for more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752363/token-startelement-in-state-endrootelement-would-result-in-an-invalid-xml-docume

Comment: @targarian Include this after `xmlTextWriter.WriteStartDocument(); xmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement("BatchFile"); .... xmlTextWriter.WriteEndDocument();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to write the outermost StartElement `<BatchElement>`.

Adding he following should fix your problem;

```
StringWriter stringwriter = new StringWriter();
XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringwriter);
xmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
xmlTextWriter.WriteStartDocument();

xmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement("BatchElement");

xmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement("BatchFileHeader");
xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("MessageType", "MSG103"); 
xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("MessageVersion", "456"); 
xmlTextWriter.WriteEndElement();

xmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement("Vendor");
xmlTextWriter.WriteElementString("Vendor", "VVV"); 
xmlTextWriter.WriteEndElement();

xmlTextWriter.WriteEndElement();
xmlTextWriter.WriteEndDocument();
```

Comment: Thanks. I had no outermost element, which was the reason for the error.